# Язык для загрузчика-дешифровщика

Tags: c#

Пишу криптор C#-программ. С криптованием проблем не возникло (криптую секцию .text), но запоролся на написании загрузчкиа-дешифровщика. Понимаю, что для таких дел берут ассемблер, но вот я думаю: есть ли возможность обойтись языками высокого уровня? Пожалуйста, натолкните на идею.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что стоит сделать, это посмотреть нельзя ли обойтись уже существующими средствами. Если нет ограничений на лицензию, можно взять упаковщик [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) (там GPL со специальным дополнением для сжатых исполняемых файлов).

Можно ли сделать загрузчик-дешифровщик без ассемблера? Это возможно, но затруднительно. Формат исполняемого файла для C++ отличается от формата исполняемого файла для C#, в первом случае основное содержимое - машинный код, во втором - IL-код. Соответственно, исполнение передается сначала стандартному PE-заголовку, затем специальной заглушке и уже затем JIT-компилятору .NET.

В обычном C++ можно было бы разбить код на несколько секций, так чтобы одна из секций была незашифрована, а остальные зашифрованы, и передать передать управление этой незашифрованной секции для расшифровки остальных. Поскольку при сборке C# контроль над секциями и т.п. отсутствует, то остается только воздействовать на уже собранный файл, то есть патчить его.

Можно попробовать сделать так:

- скомпилировать и собрать код на C#,
- скомпилировать код на C++ (шифровка-зашифровка),
- добавить объектный код С++ в объектный код C# чем-то вроде binutis,
- попатчить точки входа-выхода.

Comment: Спасибо за подробность, буду исследовать в этом направлении!

Comment: А какие системные функции мне могут понадобиться для расшифровки "на лету"? То есть идея моего криптора в том, чтобы зашифровать секцию .text (с байт-кодом и метаданными), а загрузчик должен расшифровывать её перед исполнением. Я так понимаю, расшифровывать мне придётся уже спроецированную в память секцию .text, а не файл на диске? Может быть я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: По функциям, к сожалению, сейчас не скажу. Вообще возможный вариант такой: 1) пропатчить секцию .text как записываемую, 2) добавить секцию .boot, 3) поменять точку входу на .boot, 4) в .boot добавить расшифровку, которая переписывает .text сам на себя. Но дело это трудоемкое, лучше сначала поискать в сети, может что-то готовое найдется.

Comment: Вот я как раз примерно так и планировал сделать, но вся загвоздка для меня - в расшифровщике! Добавить секцию и переписать точку входа можно и на C#, а вот что делать с загрузчиком - я пока ещё не придумал.